# Text file into Excel VBA empty line new column

Tags: vba, excel

I have sheets of data in txt files single column. I need to import into Excel and break each field into break into new columns at the empty line. I am not sure if it best to do this in the import or to do this after the import.

```
Foobar
detail1
detail2
val1
val2
val3
val4
randominfo

Widget
detail1
detail2
val1
val2
val3
val4
randominfo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to read the file in line by line and just move over when you read the empty line.

Edit: Forgot to answer your question...just do it on the import. The other way makes you scan the list again and is not efficient.

```
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer

''Initialize
r = 2
c = 1

''I'm assuming you have row headers or something so row starts at two.
''change to 1 if you want the data to be in the first row.

Open [your file path here] For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
     Line Input #1, readLine
     If readLine = "" Then
        'Index over one column
        'Start row indexer over
        c = c + 1
        r = 2

     Else
        'Output "readLine" to the sheet
        ActiveSheet.Cells(r, c).Value = readLine
        'Index down one row
        r = r + 1
     End If


Loop

Close #1
```

Comment: Thank you, I may need my hand held a little more though. Can you suggest where I can look for the remaining code?

Comment: Just maintain two variables. `r` and `c` (row and column). As you write into the rows, increment `r`. When you write into a new column, increment `c` and reset `r`. You can use `Cell.Value` or `Range.Value` to change the value of a cell. I would look for tutorials on how to do that. There are plenty around.

Comment: Sure, I know I can use  `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select`  to move column, Do I need to set a counter to return to the first row of that column?

Comment: `ActiveCell.Offset(-r, 1).Select`    Is not correct ?